# Empty view, with only clickable borders

Tags: ios, swift3

I need to have a view with borders, and only borders should be clickable.

Here is my code which creates custom view, but when I added gesture all view becomes clickable.

```
class RectangleView: UIView {

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let aPath = UIBezierPath()
    aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y: 0))
    aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width, y: 0))
    aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width, y:rect.height))
    aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:rect.height))
    aPath.close()
    UIColor.green.setStroke()
    aPath.stroke()
    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    aPath.fill()
  }
}
```

Edited, here is the screenshot from other app
[image]

so I will click on view under my top view, this one will be in front and will be clickable, so I cant add smaller subView

Comment: Just put a smaller view with user interaction disabled in front of the view.

Comment: in that case other views will not be clickable, if they will be under top view
I have edited my question, please look at iamge

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where's your code for handling tapping on the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most correct way here is to override `func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool` for `UIView` subclass.

Here is example:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupShapeLayer()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupShapeLayer() {
        //Draw your own shape here

        shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

        let innerPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: frame.width / 3, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)

        let outerPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: frame.width / 4, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)

        //Subtract inner path
        innerPath.append(outerPath.reversing())

        shapeLayer.path = innerPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return shapeLayer.path?.contains(point) ?? false
    }
}
```

Now you can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to check how it works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let customView = CustomView.init(frame: view.frame)
        view.addSubview(customView)

        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    @objc func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = sender.location(in: sender.view)
        let subview = view?.hitTest(location, with: nil)

        if subview is CustomView {
            resultLabel.text = "CustomView"
        }
        else {
            resultLabel.text = "Other"
        }
    }
}
```

Result of `tapAction`:

[image]

If you need several views, there are two possible options:

- Store `CAShapeLayer` inside one `CustomView` and iterate through it inside `point` function
- Add `CustomView` for each instance and iterate it through inside `UITapGestureRecognizer` tap action